# Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Iterable<string, Date>' and 'Date'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I write this code to get the sum about date range but I am facing with this problem

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to types 'Iterable' and
>   'Date'.

Here is my code

```
export function getTotalYearCosts(valueItem: ValueItem, allCosts: Map<string, Costs>): TotalCosts {
const totalYearCosts = { planned: 0, actual: 0 };
const test = allCosts.map(({created}) => created);

const Q1 = new Date('2018-01-01');
const Q2 = new Date('2018-04-01');
totalYearCosts.actual = valueItem.actualCostIds
  .map(costId => allCosts.get(costId, emptyCosts()).costs)
  .filter(costs => test > Q1 && test < Q2)
  .reduce((reduction, costs) => reduction + costs, 0);

totalYearCosts.planned = valueItem.plannedCostIds
  .map(costId => allCosts.get(costId, emptyCosts()).costs)
  .reduce((reduction, costs) => reduction + costs, 0);

  return totalYearCosts;
}
```

Interface of the Costs

```
export interface Costs {
  id: string;
  created: Date;
  costs: number;
 // costType: number;
  type: number;
  reference: string;
  comment: string;
}
```

Comment: `allCosts.map(({created}) => created);` doesn't return a `Date`, and the error is telling you that you can't compare a date against something else with the `>` operator

Comment: What do you suggest me to do in this case to compare date and sum the costs by the date range ?

Comment: What would you expect `test ` to be?

Comment: I have costs like Object of Interface and costs has a Date when were created I want just to if the costs(test) are greater of this Q1 and smaller of Q2 do that function reduction + costs.
I will update the code to see the interface of the Costs

Comment: @bugs Can you help me in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this.

```
export function getTotalYearCosts(valueItem: ValueItem, allCosts: Map<string, Costs>): ActualCosts {
const totalYearCosts = { actual: 0, planned: 0, Q1: 0, Q2: 0, Q3: 0, Q4: 0 };
  const iter = allCosts[Symbol.iterator]();

for (let i = 0; i < valueItem.actualCostIds.length; i++) {
  const costID = valueItem.actualCostIds[i];

  if (allCosts.get(costID).created.getMonth() < 3 && allCosts.get(costID).created.getMonth() >= 0 ) {

  totalYearCosts.actual += allCosts.get(costID).costs;
  totalYearCosts.Q1 += allCosts.get(costID).costs;
```